# Why the html file showing 240 images one by one as movie is slow in iPad?

Tags: jquery, movie

The following links shows file you can test it in iPad.
You can check it [here](http://www.xstpl.com/virtualvehicle/)
I have used jQuery to show the images as video

Answer (score 1):

Because the I pad has 512MB of RAM and your page is 8.5 MB. Fully loaded it looks like >500MB in the browser. It takes for ever to load and it is even slow on my PC with 2GB RAM. If you want a movie, just [make one](http://www.windowsmoviemakers.net/Tutorials/HowToVideoSlideShow.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the browser to load 240 large images (1000 x 700px) Downloading all those resources will take some time. There is little need to dump so much data on the client since large parts of the image do not change at all.

Consider deploying movie as movie file or animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of jQuery but jQuery animations are laggy as are.
 `10MB page of 240 images + the I pad (slower than a computer) = your results`
 In this case mooTools will be better but even then I would expect issues. images are not intended to be used like this.